# How to change NX webpack configuration in order to use dynamic imports in an express app?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, path, webpack-dev-server

I am using this NX package to do a monorepo, I created an express app following this [commands](https://nx.dev/packages/express) .

However, I can't do the dynamic imports. I don't know how to solve this. I use webpack as bundler( it was preconfigurated ).
How can I solve this?
I got this error `Error: Cannot find module`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use babel for that.
Check out
https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

It should also show you how to update your webpack config.